# Making a numpy array from bytes packed with struct

Tags: python, numpy

The following piece of python code:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

arr = []
arr.append(struct.pack('ii', 1, 3))
arr.append(struct.pack('ii', 2, 4))
dt = np.dtype([('n','i4'),('m','i4')])

a = np.array(arr,dt)
print(a)
```

returns with `[(1, 3) (2, 4)]` (as I expected) under `Numpy` version `1.13.3` but under version `1.14.5` it fails with:

```
a = np.array(arr,dt)  
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
```

Is this a feature or a bug? I would like to get this to work under `1.14.5` as it does under `1.13.3` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this in **`1.14`** by using **`frombuffer`**

```
>>> np.frombuffer(np.array(arr), dt)
array([(1, 3), (2, 4)], dtype=[('n', '<i4'), ('m', '<i4')])
```

---

I *believe* this has to do with the [changes to **`fromstring`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/release.html#deprecations) that appeared in `numpy 1.14`, although I would appreciate it if someone can verify.